# Car screams after 14-day non-use upon start-up

Tags: battery, noise, g35, infiniti

On two occasions since I purchased my 2004 Infinity G35 a year ago, the car was garaged for more than 10 days without being started. When I did start it, the engine screamed at me as I backed the car out. When I shfted into Drive and accelerated slightly, it screamed for a few more seconds, then stopped screaming. This happened once, then I drove the car for a two-week period and it was garaged again, resulting in the same action. Help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the battery was drained someone, but not enough to keep it from starting. Upon starting, the alternator went into overdrive trying to recharge it. In doing so, the serpentine belt slipped some in complaint until it got warm enough to keep a tighter grip and/or the battery had recharged enough to allow the alternator to chill out a little.

Two things here:

- You may need a new serpentine belt. If the one you have is old, it may be slipping due to not being able to have enough grip.
- If you are going to let your car sit for a similar amount of time, you may want to put a trickle charger on it while the car sits, or consider disconnecting the battery. Every car has a small amount of parasitic loss at the battery and yours is no different.